# How to get false as initial state Datastore in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How to get false as initial state Datastore in Jetpack Compose? I would initial state be false. I changed it to false in CollectAsState() but it always return true.

```
class DataStoreUtil(private val context: Context) {

    companion object {
        private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<androidx.datastore.preferences.core.Preferences> by preferencesDataStore("settings")
        val FORCE_DARK_THEME = booleanPreferencesKey("force_dark_theme")

    }

    val getForceDarkTheme: Flow<Boolean> = context.dataStore.data
        .map { preferences ->
            preferences[FORCE_DARK_THEME] ?: true
        }

    suspend fun saveForceDarkTheme(value: Boolean) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[FORCE_DARK_THEME] = value
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MySwitch() {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val dataStore = DataStoreUtil(LocalContext.current)
    val switchState by dataStore.getForceDarkTheme.collectAsState(false)
   
    Switch(
        checked = switchState,
        onCheckedChange = {
            scope.launch{
                dataStore.saveForceDarkTheme(it)
            }
        }
    )
    Text(
        text = if(switchState) "foo" else "bar",
    )
}
```

Comment: If no value exists, you are returning `true` here `?: true` for `getForceDarkTheme`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle scenarios where there is no value present in the data store you can change to,

```
val getForceDarkTheme: Flow<Boolean?> = context.dataStore.data
    .map { preferences ->
        preferences[FORCE_DARK_THEME]
    }
```

This returns `null` when there is no value and you can do `null` check and use required logic.